# Accessing the document a SQL view's row refers to

Tags: marklogic

In a MarkLogic SQL view, the __docid system column contains the URI of the fragment that the view row was created from (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_10453).  How can the URI of the document that this fragment refers to be determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an internal number which is not very useful elsewhere. I'd add a column containing the uri of the document, and use that instead. You can use `xdmp:node-uri(.)` in TDE to get the document uri.

HTH!